# combine a char and an int to a string

Tags: c++

For example;

```
int i = 1;
char c = 'V';
string s;
```

Result:

```
s = "1 V"
```

Can anybody tell me how to do that?
Thank you

Comment: FYI it's called lexical conversion, followed by concatenation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `std::stringstream` from `<sstream>` header file, as:

```
#include <sstream>

int i = 1;
char c = 'V';

std::stringstream ss;
ss << i << " " << c;
std::string s = ss.str();
std::cout << s;
```

Output:

```
1 V
```

---

I've implemented `stringbuilder` using which you can do this just in one line:

```
std::string s = stringbuilder() << i << " " << c;
```

Here is the implementation of `stringbuilder`:

```
struct stringbuilder
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   template<typename T>
   stringbuilder & operator << (const T &data)
   {
        ss << data;
        return *this;
   }
   operator std::string() { return ss.str(); }
};
```

Comment: thank Nawaz, and if I use streamstring, how can i clear it for the next time when I want to use it again? i tried ss.flush() and ss.clear() but they didnot work

Comment: @user552279: Do `ss.str("")` to make `ss` empty, as @ildjarn suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
stringstream str;

str<<< i << c;

string s=str.str();
```