# Using the '<<' operator when supplying argument to functions

Tags: c++, ns-3

I've been programming the ns3 network simulator which is written in c++. There are a bunch of functions for logging output conditionally, depending on how the system is configured. (ie the statement to log the message is always there but if I turn off debugging then some messages won't come out).

Calling one of these functions might look like this:

```
int n=42;  
NS_LOG_LOGIC("the answer is " << n);
```

Which is extremely useful since it allows me to directly concatenate many different kinds of data into a single string to be logged.

Now I'm trying to write my own logging function to allow me more control over where messages are logged and to allow me to insert a unique id and timestamp before every message so I know where and when it came from.

My question is this - how do I create a function in c++ which can be called in this way? I cant find the source for the function shown and haven't seen any other examples of functions like this.

Note - regular '+' concatenation isn't good enough since I want to be able to easily concatenate a bunch of different data types. I know there are other ways to do that but I also just want to figure out what is going on in the function above!

Thank you :)

Comment: This is **NOT** a function, it is a macro. (Which means you shoudl be able to find the source, `man grep` is your friend)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this. It will print the expression to the standard output if `DEBUG` is defined.
It supposes `#include <iostream>`.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#  define NS_LOG_LOGIC( expr ) \
      std::cout << expr << std::endl;  // or "\n" instead of endl if performance matters more than reliability
#else
#  define NS_LOG_LOGIC( expr )
#endif
```

### EDIT

As properly noted by Tony :

- `std::endl` will print a new line **and** flush your buffer, it will be slower but you get more guarantee that your logs has been written in case of a crash. `\n` simply prints a new line, the buffer is not flushed.
- use the `do { ... } while(false)` notation helps macro reliability.

Comment: `#define NS_LOG_LOGIC(expr) do { std::cout << expr << '\n'; } while (false)` or another notation that works properly inside `if`/`else` statements should be used. Thought I understand where you're coming from, suggesting `'\n'` is less "reliable" without explanation unfairly begs more questions. Personally, I prefer `std::cerr` for the logging situations where line buffering is generally useful.  Separately, it's noteworthy that using all-uppercase identifiers exclusively for preprocessor macros is a common and best practice.

Answer (score 0):

A simple stringbuilder class can be helpful in these sorts of concatenation scenarios – even in the more general case where you need to pass the eventual string as an argument or something (i.e., not just log it).

For a sample implementation, see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5770312/19254